# Which types of loops are appropriate for re-entering answers in a Java program?

Tags: java, loops, input

I am currently working on a program that compares the distinct salaries of 2 individuals for the last 5 years. Most of this program will require arrays and loops. I already have my arrays taken care of, but I need to figure out which loops are appropriate for certain situations. I understand that using only if-else conditions is not good enough to make a good program. I need to know what loop is appropriate enough for the following scenario:

```
if (firstIndividualSalary[0] == secondIndividualSalary[0]) {
    System.out.println(“Error. Try again.”);
}

if (firstIndividualSalary[1] == secondIndividualSalary[1]) {
    System.out.println(“Error. Try again.”);
}

if (firstIndividualSalary[2] == secondIndividualSalary[2]) {
    System.out.println(“Error. Try again.”);
}

if (firstIndividualSalary[3] == secondIndividualSalary[3]) {
    System.out.println(“Error. Try again.”);
}

if (firstIndividualSalary[4] == secondIndividualSalary[4]) {
    System.out.println(“Error. Try again.”);
}
```

In the above situation, if the salaries for the 2 individuals for a particular year (any of the 5 years) is exactly the same, then the program will print an error and make the user re-enter both salaries for that year. One major requirement of my program is that none of the salaries for any of the 5 years should match each other at all. Please let me know what loops you would use for situations involving correcting your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate arrays you can use a for loop like:

```
boolean areAllDifferent = true;
for (int i = 0; i < firstIndividualSalary.length && i < secondIndividualSalary.length; i++) {
    if (firstIndividualSalary[i] == secondIndividualSalary[i]) {
        System.out.println("Error. Try again.");
        areAllDifferent = false;
    }
}
// boolean areAllDifferent now contains if the user inputed valid salaries
```

Comment: I tried that, but I use NetBeans and when I entered my version of your code suggestion, one error said "not a statement, illegal start of expression" and another said "cannot find symbol". Should I present my entire code to show what problems I'm really working with? Do you have any more loop suggestions such as the while loop or a do-while loop?

Comment: Please share your full code. Note that I have edited the answer as the symbol " was in a different encoding.

Comment: @PaulMAVA I put out the full code as per the following link: stackoverflow.com/q/61596421/13325231 perhaps you can help me figure out what needs loops or not.